# Compare object to class in typescript?

Tags: typescript, interface

Is it possible in typescript to compare a given object to an interface or a class?

My first thought was to compare using `typeof` against an interface but this failed:

```
interface EmployeeModel {
  id?: string,
  employee_name?: string,
  employee_salary?: string,
  employee_age?: string,
  profile_image?: string,
}
```

```
const employee = response.body.pop();
if (typeof employee === EmployeeModel) {
  next();
}
```

I thought to convert the interface to a class and use instaceof but this also does not work:

```
class EmployeeModel {
  id?: string;
  employee_name?: string;
  employee_salary?: string;
  employee_age?: string;
  profile_image?: string;
}
```

```
const employee = response.body.pop();
if (employee instanceof EmployeeModel) {
  next();
}
```

How can i validate the response object of an object from an API like this?

Comment: How would you do this in JavaScript?  (That’s what TS compiles to, so any TS solution will need to also be a JS solution)

Comment: :) do you know the answer?

Comment: [You'll have to write your own test or use a framework like you found.](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/FAQ#how-do-i-check-at-run-time-if-an-object-implements-some-interface)  ... or write your own framework, I guess.  There's no magic bullet here, unfortunately.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This cannot be the most efficient answer I am sure, but using this npm package and passing `throwErrorOnAlien: true` in the options i could successfully run jest with an api call and simply check the response body by passing in an expected map generated from an openapi/swagger definition (documentation driven development).

I is a shame though, i was hoping for a more elegant solution.

```
  it('Check body response', next => {
    try {
      objectReduceByMap(
        response.body,
        EmployeesService.employeeGetResponseFormat,
        { throwErrorOnAlien: true }
      );
      next();
    } catch (e) {
      // objectReduceByMap threw an error so alien attributes were discovered in the api response.
      // Calling next with the error so Jest stops.
      next(e);
    }
  });
```

https://github.com/acrontum/openapi-nodegen-typescript-api-test-rig/blob/master/README.md